# 2.20 Question Introduction to analytic number theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, multiplicative-function

The following question is on page 48 apostol Introduction to analytic number theory( 20)

> Let $P(n)$ be the product of the positive integers which are less than equal to $n$ and relatively prime to $n$.

Then prove that $ P(n) = n^{\phi(n) } \prod_{d|n} {(\frac{ d! }{d^d})}^{\mu(n/d) } $ .

I tried by manipulating RHS and noting that function on RHS is multiplicative but I have been not successful.

So, can you please help me.

Comment: The usual way for multiplicative functions is to start by showing it's true when $n$ is prime, then when $n$ is a prime power.

Comment: @GerryMyerson i have tried it but couldn't prove it.

Comment: $P(n)=\prod_{m\le n,\gcd(m,n)=1} m$ isn't multiplicative. The formula follows from the inclusion exclusion principle $$P(n)=\prod_{m\le n} m^{\sum_{d| \gcd(n,m)}\mu(d)}=\prod_{d|n} (\prod_{m \le n,d| m} m)^{\mu(d)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Simple rearrangment followed by taking logarithm of both  sides yields
$$S(n) = \sum_{m \leq n, (m,n) = 1}\log\bigg(\dfrac{m}{n}  \bigg) = \sum_{d|n}\mu(n/d)T(d)$$
Where $T(n) = \log (n!/n^n)$. Now by applying the mobius inversion formula $S = \mu * T$ if and only if $T = S*u$. That is
$$\log(n!/n) = \sum_{d|n} \sum_{m\leq d, (m,d) = 1} \log(m/d)$$

Hence it suffices to show that
$$\dfrac{n!}{n^n} = \prod_{d|n}\prod_{m\leq d, (m,d) = 1}\dfrac{m}{d} $$.

This simpler to work with. One way to show the equation is true uses the following lemma.

*The set*
$$S = \{ m\cdot n/d | d \text{ divides } n,\  1 \leq m \leq d,\  (m,d) = 1 \}$$
*runs through every number modulo $n$ exactly once.*\

You can show that this lemma is true easily(Hint: Show that $S \subseteq \{1, \dots , n\}$ and $\{1, \dots , n\} \subseteq S$.)

Returning back to that last product formula, you can see that
$$\prod_{d|n}\prod_{m\leq d, (m,d) = 1}\dfrac{m}{d} = 
\prod_{d|n}\prod_{m\leq d, (m,d) = 1}\dfrac{mn/d}{n} = \dfrac{n!}{n^n} $$

Comment: I am unable to deduce how you wrote,
$S(n)=∑_{m≤n,(m,n)=1}log(m/n)=∑_{d|n}μ(n/d)T(d)$ . Can you please explain